# Gulp won't install on mac

Tags: permissions, npm

Gulp installs without any persmissions error messages.

```
npm install --global gulp 

npm install --global gulp-cli
```

But does not run.

```
> gulp                                                                                                                                         
[15:58:12] Local gulp not found in ~
[15:58:12] Try running: npm install gulp
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For some reason my /usr/local/lib/node_modules file ended up under the 'wheel' group but with the correct user. Correcting the permissions fixed the issue without needing to reinstall gulp.

```
sudo chown -R username:admin node_modules
```

Comment: Just do `sudo npm install <package>` for a one-off root installation.